# How to detect if view was created by an extension?

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema, postgresql-extensions

In PostgreSQL on how can one know whether a specific view was created by an extension?

**What SQL query must be executed to find out?** No manual solutions.

Comment: Don't think this is possible without some kind of auditing table.

Comment: As stated in the question (and now also highlighted in bold) )I am looking for a SQL query. No manual inspections. The solution (if there is one) will most likely involve the information_schema.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the view shows up in `\dx+` output in `psql -E`.

This will also show the queries that psql uses to get the result, which will help you construct a query.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I specifically asked for a SQL query.

Comment: I have extended the answer; maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Axel Fontaine pays attention to what Laurenz Albe says

with \ dx + output in psql -E. I got the following query (replace pg_stat_statements by your extension ):

```
SELECT c.relname FROM pg_catalog.pg_depend join pg_class c  on (c.oid=pg_depend.objid) WHERE refclassid = 'pg_catalog.pg_extension'::pg_catalog.regclass AND deptype = 'e'  AND refobjid = ( SELECT  e.oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension e WHERE e.extname='pg_stat_statements') and c.relkind='v' ORDER BY 1;
```

;-)